# Keep getting error message"operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (2,)" How do I get solve this?

Tags: python

my problem is that i'm trying to create a function in python that takes the input of two vectors; `M = metabolic` heat production and `g = thermal` conductance, and returns and output `T`, which is a Nm x Ng(where N = number of elements in the concerned vector) matrix that contains the values for survival temperatures. These values come the formula T_f and they need to be inserted into the matrix T. 
   My problem is that every time I try to run my code i get the error message:

```
operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (2,).
```

Where the error message originates from the T_f formula. How do i solve this and how do i take the values from T_f and combine them into the matrix T? 
My code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
def survivalTemperature(M,g):
    if (np.all([M])>=50 or np.all([M]) <=500) or (np.all([g])>=0.04 or np.all([g])<=0.45):
        T_f = 36-(((0.9*M-12)*(g+0.95))/27.8)
        T = T_f
    else:
        T = "RangeError"
    return T
print(survivalTemperature(np.array([50,200,300]),np.array([0.20,0.14])))
```

Answer (score 0):

Both arrays, must be the same shape. On the last line one has `3` elements, and the other has `2`. They would both have to have the same amount of element see [Numpy Broadcasting Rules](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) for more help.